Не регистрирует ответы пользователя в переменные в TeleBot
Не регистрирует текст пользователя в переменные, помогите, пожалуйста. На выводе то же самое, что и в кавычках. Вместо переменной значение не подставляется.
Код:
def welcome(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = 'Введи мемо:')

    memo = (message.text)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_memo)

def input_memo(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мемо : {memo}, теперь введи адрес биржи") 

    address = message.text

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_address)

def input_address(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Мемо : {memo}, адрес биржи : {address}, теперь введи сумму")

    summa = message.text

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, final_message)

def final_message(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправляю сумму {summa} по адресу {address} с мемо {memo}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bot.polling(non_stop = True)


Ну, в показанном коде нет никаких причин для того, чтобы что-то куда-то подставлялось, вы написали самые обычные строки

А если вы всё-таки сделаете подстановку — питон начнёт ругаться на использование несуществующих переменных
